# Please tell me name of this action in flutter (when pressing on item in tabbar)

Tags: flutter, tabbar

When I tap on a item on tab bar a circle will appear and disappear, please tell me name of this animation and how could I implement it in a flutter

[click for seeing sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y64KR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is called a ripple. And you can get it by wrapping a widget in an `Inkwell`.

See more here about it here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/ripples

Answer (score 0):

Hi In Scaffold BottomNavigationBar() has inbuilt properties of circle appear and disappear

Answer (score 0):

You can use a widget called Gesture Detector which also has ripple effect